# String and 2 letters

Tags: java, regex, string

Hello I am a student and my question in better detail is this.

> Given a string and two letters (c1 and c2), return a count of the number of times "axb" occurs in the string, where x is any character. For example, given the string "antiaircraft" and the letters 'a' and 't', your method should return 2. The three-letter patterns may overlap. For example, "aaaa" has two occurrences of "axa".

Now what I have written down so far is

```
public int countAxA(String str, char c1, char c2) {

 int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) == c2)
        {
             count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

So according to the my homework some of the inputs work but others do not. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: use equals() with String

Comment: What is `c1` and `c2`? do you want to find the occurrences of `c1xc2` ?

Comment: @KorayTugay so would I do c1.equals(c2)?

Comment: @KorayTugay these are `char` primitives, `==` is the correct way to compare them.

Comment: @User_Targaryen unfortunately that is all the question gives me and I am just as equally confused as you are in this case.

Comment: For describing such cases learn about [tag:regex]. In this case, you would say: for given a,b, count the number of matches `a.b`.

Comment: You're not using `c1` in your method. Since the assignment says you should look for occurrences of `c1`, then any character, then `c2`, how come that you are surprised that your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int countAxA(String str, char c1, char c2) {

 int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) == c1)
        {
             if(i+2 < str.length() && str.charAt(i+2) == c2)
                count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Try this out!!!

Comment: Ahh so i was missing the the if statement with the logical and operator. Thanks it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @SktSkat check my answer - it's more general.

Comment: Why not `for (int i=0; i < str.length()-2; i++)`? No point in checking `i` against `str.length()` twice.

Comment: I wanted the code to be as similar as the code given in the question, for the author's easier understanding

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate once and keep track, and if you happen to find the first character then do a lookahead:

```
public int countAxA(String s, char one, char two) {
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length - 2; i++) { //don't need to go beyond 3rd last char
        if (cs[i] == one && cs[i + 2] == two) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You need to return a count, not true or false

Comment: Whoops, easily fixed.

Comment: You don't need to get the char array. That necessarily makes a copy of the string's char array (because a char array is mutable). Just use `charAt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int countAxA(String str, char c1, char c2) {


int count = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < str.length()-2; i++)
   {
    if (str.charAt(i) == c1 && str.charAt(i+2) == c2)
      {
          count++;
      }
    }
   return count;

}
```

try this..
you are checking c2 only,
so, 
tanticarft as input will result into output:-3

but you have to check c1 and c2 both

Answer (score 0):

Considering your assignment instructions, your program should be longer. what you are doing here

`if (str.charAt(i) == c2)
        {
             count++;
        }`

is just counting how many times the character c2 occurs.

try using something like this,

```
if(str.charAt(x)==c1 && str.charAt(x+2) ==c2) 
    count ++
```

with this statement you are now checking if axb exists and adding 1 to count every time you run into an occurrence of axb.

Comment: add a check statement  for `x+2` if it goes out of bounds

Comment: @User_Targaryen Yes you are correct, but being a student myself, I know it is not good to spoon feed answers. I took too much advantage of google and for a year I coded without ever learning to code. But yes you have to make sure you stay within bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You were on right track.

```
public int countAxA(String str, char c1, char c2) 
    {
       int count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) 
       {
         if (str.charAt(i) == c1 && i +2 < str.length && str.charAt(i+2) == c2) 
        { 
          count++;
        } 
       }
     return count; 
}
```

1. Loop over every character in str.
2. Check whether current char is equal to c1
3. If so then check if current index + 2 is not out of bounds
4. Then check for c2 at current index + 2
5. Finally if all condition are met then increment count;

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

```
int count=0, incrementCounter=2;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)==c1){
                if(str.charAt(i+incrementCounter)==c2 && incrementCounter<=str.length()){
                    i = i+incrementCounter;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```